# Terminal Startup command not found

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

Whenever I open my terminal there is a line that reads,

```
-bash: 6ee67d3f2005ceaf5266c966198b7f3c165bf5d7: command not found
```

This is shown after the line that states my last login information.

I am trying to get rid of this from my terminal since I don't remember how it got there and it serves no purpose to me. How would I get rid of this line? Im new to using the terminal but any information is helpful.

Here is the echo $PATH information:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent :) Please copy and paste the output of `echo $PATH` and add it to your question.

Comment: Have you looked at your .bash_profile file? It's in your home directory.

Comment: Oh with these comments I think Im starting to see where it is coming from. It is coming from the echo $PATH right? I also input nano .bash_profile and I saw the same information. If that is the case how would I get rid of it from terminal?

Comment: Fixed the problem! In nano .bash_profile I took out the first line that said source .bashrc. Thank you guys for your help!!

Comment: @PRJCT_C Great you found out what the culprit was, please add an answer with that information and accept it to close your question. Otherwise, your question will be listed as unanswered (although it is actually solved) and will draw other user's attention unnecessarily.

Comment: However removing the whole.bashrc is not a good idea as it removes a lot. Better find and remove the one line causing the issue. Show us the file if you need more info.

Comment: I thought I found the answer but I am not fully done yet. When I open my terminal it no longer says( -bash: 6ee67d3f2005ceaf5266c966198b7f3c165bf5d7: command not found), however if I input /bin/bash then it will show up. Not sure how I would access this information to get rid of it. The next line after that says (bash-3.2$ )